# Loop All button text in form

Tags: java, loops, button

I'm trying to do a loop thru all the button text in a form, but i can't find any solution for Java !!

i did something like :

```
 for(JButton temp : this)
 {
        if(JButton.getText() == "A")
        {
          JButton.enabled(false);
        }
 }
```

but no luck

p.s. my problem is not about the equals statement !! I want to loop thru all button in my window.

here is the working result thanks to MadProgrammer:

```
for(Component comp : jPanel2.getComponents()) 
            {
                if(comp instanceof JButton)
                {
                   JButton btn = (JButton)comp;                       
                   if(btn.getText().equals("A")) 
                   {
                     btn.setEnabled(false); 
                   }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer Possible XY problem ? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems...

`for(JButton temp : this)` simply doesn't make sense, unless `this` implements `Iterable<JButton>`

`if(JButton.getText() == "A")` has two issues.  The first is, `getText()` isn't a `static` method, so it can't be called in this manner, the second is, `==` shouldn't be used to compare `String` values...

`JButton.enabled(false);` has two issues.  The first is, `enabled` isn't `static` and `enabled` is actually depreciated, so you should avoid using it.  Instead using `setEnabled`

Without know how you buttons are actually managed, it's impossible to provide you an accurate solution.

If you are trying to iterate through the buttons on a `Container` of some kind, you might use something like...

```
for (Component comp : container.getComponents()) {
    if (comp instanceof JButton) { 
        //...
    }
}
```

For example.

If the buttons are stored in some kind of `java.util.List`, you could using something like...

```
for (JButton button : listOfButtons) {
    //...
}
```

In order to check the button text, you should use something like (using the previous example as a base)...

```
if ("A".equals(button.getText()) {...}
```

Take a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details

Comment: Hello if i use :  for (Component comp : container.getComponents()) {
    if (comp instanceof JButton) { 
        //...
    }
}   how do i get the text of Comp ?

Comment: @Robyseb You cast the reference to a `JButton` first.  `JButton btn = (JButton)comp;`, hence the need for `instanceof`

Comment: ok great ... i was not spelling it right but now it work perfectly thank you i update my top post with the final result

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [String compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

```
      if("A".equals(temp.getText())) // or use if("A".equalsIgnoreCase(temp.getText()))
        {
          temp.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

instead of

```
      if(JButton.getText() == "A")
        {
          JButton.enabled(false);
        }
```

Comment: **FYI**: According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#enable(boolean)), `enable` is *Deprecated*. `setEnabled` should be used instead.

Comment: `"A".equals(temp.getText())` will protect you against `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is `==` sign. Whenever you compare the values of two objects, here being `String`, you use the `equals()` method instead of `==`.

The operator `==` is for primitive types. In case of objects, it will compare the addresses instead of the object's value. On the other hand, `equals()` will actually compare the values.

Try:

```
for(JButton temp : listOfButtons) // I changed the iterable here.
 {
        if("A".equals(temp.getText())) // notice who the caller to .equals() is. It is "A"
        {
          temp.setEnabled(false); // make temp disabled
        }
 }
```

*Not being harsh but the code that you were using was completely flawed. I corrected the errors; see if that works for you.*
*The errors were: **1.** Your source of buttons in the for loop was wrong. **2.** getText() was used as a static method while it is dynamic. **3.** You used an == instead of equals() **4.** setEnabled() was used as a static method instead of dynamic*

Comment: [`getText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getText()) is **not** a `static` method.

Comment: @PM77-1 That is OP's code =) I just edited it.

Comment: Excuses, excuses, ...

Comment: @PM77-1 I actually didn't notice it. I saw the error in the loop and decided to examine further :-P Thanks for linking to the docs of `getText()` though

Comment: Hi i understand about the .equals but the problem i have is to iterate thru all button ! i took the example of Little Child but "listOfButtons" cannot be found ??

Comment: @Robyseb You stated that you want to loop over the buttons. To loop using the `for:each` loop, you must store them somewhere like in a `Vector<>` or in an `ArrayList<>`. Where did you store the buttons? :)

Comment: `"A".equals(temp.getText())` will protect you against `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thank you Little child you understand my problem lol ... my button are actually not store anywhere as Netbeans create them as i draw them ! They might be store by default but i dont know where ?

Comment: @Robyseb LoL that is why I prefer to make my GUI via code and not drag and drop ;-) *I prefer Eclipse, btw*

Comment: NetBeans create the button with these variable "private javax.swing.JButton jButtonA;" any other idea ?

Comment: So it is creating single instances. You need to learn how to create and store buttons in loops. It is fairly easy =)